# History api + ee + ajax

Tags: url

I'm trying to create something similar like http://pinterest.com
a popup with a magical url rewrite.

I'm wondering if anyone tried something similar?

There is a tutorial to do staticly here: http://html5doctor.com/history-api/
But i'm wondering how to do this dynamical with every new entry

the possibilities so far could be : 
- adjusting the script with EE tags (creating a super long javascript though)
- perhaps nsm-htaccess-generator to create the httaccess with every new entry ?
- a way to detect in which page i currently am

any other idea's how to handle this?
thanks

Comment: I doubt this will be easy to do, unless you have a really good knowledge of JS and PHP programming. It has nothing to do with htaccess though.

Comment: The question is a little too open-ended. Can you make it more specific and more relevant to EE? If you posted some working template code and asked "how can I insert my current url into this script" that might help us answer this question.